# Vue.js access imported JSON

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to Vue and I'm importing a json file via axios and it's displaying on the DOM. Now my question is how can I target elements inside the json file in vue, or how can I pass it thru to the new Vue element? I can target it with the computed output function in the vue chrome dev tool. But I just can find a way to get it in to target it inside the new Vue so I can put inside my html. For example how can I pass the data from address --> city?
Here is my Json:

```
{
  "restaurant": [
{
  "address": {
    "city": "Berlin",
    "country_code": "DE",
    "id": 12345,
    "latitude": 12345,
    "longitude": 12345,
    "street": "Muster Stra\u00dfe",
    "street_no": "43",
    "zipcode": "12627"
  },
  "chain": {
    "group_name": null,
    "id": 123,
    "key_account": false,
    "name": "XXX"
  },
  "created_ts": "2017-09-15T09:23:37.707020+00:00",
  "custom_data": null,
  "deleted": false,
  "emails": [
    {
      "email": "firstname_883.lastname_883@xxx.com",
      "email_type": "general",
      "id": 123456,
      "imprint": false
    }
  ],
  "global_id": "123456",
  "id": 123456,
  "modified_ts": "2017-11-30T12:10:13.298887+00:00",
  "owner": {
    "business_entity": null,
    "company": "XXX",
    "id": 123456,
    "managing_directors": "",
    "name": "Herr XXX",
    "registration_court": "",
    "registration_number": "",
    "tax_number": ""
  },
  "phones": [
    {
      "id": 123456,
      "imprint": false,
      "phone_number": "+4930123456",
      "phone_type": "fax"
    },
    {
      "id": 123456,
      "imprint": false,
      "phone_number": "+4930123456",
      "phone_type": "phone"
    }
  ],
  "platforms": {
    "LH": {
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": 123,
          "name": "XXX",
          "primary_category": true
        },
        {
          "id": 123,
          "name": "XXX",
          "primary_category": false
        }
      ],
      "custom_data": {
        "cocacola_promotion": false,
        "custom_preorder_minimum_time": "",
        "default_delivery_time": "",
        "express": false,
        "express_refund_logic": "",
        "guaranteed_delivery_time": "",
        "hide_google_places_order_action": true,
        "lh_award": false,
        "ninecookies_live_tracking": false,
        "preorder": true,
        "recommended": false,
        "white_label": "",
        "white_label_external": false,
        "white_label_offline": false
      },
      "deleted": false,
      "id": 123456,
      "key_account": true,
      "last_dowant_sync_ts": null,
      "last_salesforce_sync_ts": null,
      "name": "XXX",
      "online": true,
      "payment_methods": [
        {
          "id": 12,
          "name": "cash",
          "online_payment": false
        },
        {
          "id": 12,
          "name": "online",
          "online_payment": true
        }
      ],
      "platform": "XD",
      "platform_id": "123456",
      "reachable": true,
      "salesforce_id": "123456",
      "slug": "XXX",
      "transmissions": [
        {
          "enabled": true,
          "id": 123,
          "name": "XXX",
          "parameters": {
            "device_id": "XXX",
            "phone_number": "11"
          }
        },
        {
          "enabled": true,
          "id": 123,
          "name": "sms",
          "parameters": {
            "sms_number": "+4930123456"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "PDE": {
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": 123,
          "name": "XXX",
          "primary_category": false
        },
        {
          "id": 123,
          "name": "XXX",
          "primary_category": true
        }
      ],
      "custom_data": {
        "brand_promotion_monday": true,
        "brand_promotion_thursday": false,
        "brand_promotion_tuesday": false,
        "brand_promotion_wednesday": true,
        "cocacola_promotion": false,
        "custom_preorder_minimum_time": "",
        "default_delivery_time": "",
        "express": false,
        "express_refund_logic": "",
        "guaranteed_delivery_time": "",
        "hide_google_places_order_action": false,
        "kinder_menu": false,
        "ninecookies_live_tracking": false,
        "pde_anniversary": false,
        "preorder": true,
        "white_label": "",
        "white_label_external": false,
        "white_label_offline": false
      },
      "deleted": false,
      "id": 123456,
      "key_account": true,
      "last_dowant_sync_ts": "2017-11-30T12:20:32.887802+00:00",
      "last_salesforce_sync_ts": null,
      "name": "Pizza Max",
      "online": true,
      "payment_methods": [
        {
          "id": 37,
          "name": "cash",
          "online_payment": false
        },
        {
          "id": 38,
          "name": "online",
          "online_payment": true
        },
        {
          "id": 41,
          "name": "ec_card",
          "online_payment": false
        }
      ],
      "platform": "XXX",
      "platform_id": "123",
      "reachable": true,
      "salesforce_id": "123456",
      "slug": "musterstr-123",
      "transmissions": [
        {
          "enabled": true,
          "id": 123,
          "name": "pos_polling",
          "parameters": {
            "pos_polling_id": "123456",
            "pos_polling_password": "123456",
            "pos_polling_user": "123456"
          }
        },
        {
          "enabled": true,
          "id": 123,
          "name": "sms",
          "parameters": {
            "sms_number": "+4930123456"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }

  }]}
```

Here my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>VueJS</title>
    <script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


    <div id="app">
        <!-- <p>{{ restaurant }}</p> -->
        <p>{{ restaurant }}</p>

    </div>


    <script>
        var vm = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                restaurant: [],
                address: [],
                city: [],
            },
            mounted: function() {
                this.load();
            },
            methods: {
                load: function() {
                    this.restaurant = '...loading';
                    var vm = this;
                    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/restaurant')
                        .then(function(response) {
                            vm.restaurant = response.data;
                            console.log(vm.restaurant[0].address)
                        })
                        .catch(function(error) {
                            vm.restaurant = 'error' + error;
                        });
                }
            },
            computed: {
                output: function() {
                    return this.restaurant = vm.restaurant[0].address;
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Those are just objects; you can access their properties like any other objects.

Comment: You are still thinking in "vanilla JS/jQuery way". Vues main purpose is that you no longer need to acces the dom nodes - manually change particular elements content.

Comment: @SLaks and how would this look like? I can't get it to run

Comment: @RichardMc: The same way you render any other object properties in your ViewModel.  See the Vue tutorial.

Comment: @SLaks where do I find this tut?

Comment: The giant link right there on https://vuejs.org/

Comment: @SLaks as I'm really new to Vue, could could you just give me a small code example from my script how to do this? that would be awesome...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

restaurant is an array in your case in response. so if you just need address then we can just extract in and use it.

Please check out snippet.

I am replacing ajax call with static data you can easily replace it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>VueJS</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


    <div id="app">
        <div v-if="restaurant.length > 0">
          <!-- you can also use loop through restaurant -->
          <p>Id : {{ restaurant[0].address.id }}</p>
          <p>City : {{ restaurant[0].address.city }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    
        var yourAjaxData = {
          "restaurant": [
          {
            "address": {
              "city": "Berlin",
              "country_code": "DE",
              "id": 12345,
              "latitude": 12345,
              "longitude": 12345,
              "street": "Muster Stra\u00dfe",
              "street_no": "43",
              "zipcode": "12627"
            },
            // your other data goes on and on ...
          }]
        };
        
        var vm = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {   
                restaurant: []
            },
            mounted: function() {
                this.load();
            },
            methods: {
                load: function() {
                    this.restaurant = '...loading';
                    var vm = this;
                    // ajax call
                    
                    // return data is object
                    // inside it restaurant is key
                    // restaurant's value is array
                    vm.restaurant = yourAjaxData.restaurant;
                    
                }
            },
            computed: {
                output: function() {
                    return this.restaurant = vm.restaurant[0].address;
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That would give an error in the console, since you cannot access property address of undefined, since during the ajax call there is a short moment where `this.restaurant ` is a string

Comment: i guess i have added condition there to stop evaluation before ajax <div v-if="restaurant.length > 0">